# Tutors, Students, Courses database design

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have 3 entities: Tutors, Students, Courses

Tutors teach many courses

Students can be assigned to many courses that are taught by many tutors

Tutors and students need to be able to log into the system

I would like to represent this design using the following tables:

```
users
- id
- username
- password
- first_name
- last_name
- email
- password
- phone
- role_id (Student or Tutor or Admin)
- created
- modified

roles (Student, Tutor)
- id
- name
- created
- modified

courses (The courses that Tutors can teach and that Students can be assigned to)
- id
- name
- created
- modified

users_courses
- id
- user_id
- course_id
- created
- modified
```

The problem I have with the above design (users_courses table) is that, let's say we have Tutor A and Tutor B that teach Math. If student X is registered to that math course we can't know if student X is being tutored by Tutor A or Tutor B.

I would really like to be able to use a single users table to keep all the users to make things simple.

Any advice please?

Comment: What's the point of the roles table?  Just to store the "student/tutor" attribute of the user?  Otherwise, why not add a "tutor_id" onto the users_courses which points to the tutor for that course?

Comment: I find that weird having in a table two columns that points to the same table. I'm not sure that's good practice... @Gerik

Comment: It's actually good practice because you're storing the most minimal amount of information while providing the data that you're asking for.  If you look into topics such as self-relating tables you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Actually..just to expand on this thought to be a little more clear: consider the structure of a family.  If you had a table called person you might add attributes such as: mother, father, spouse, brother, sister (we'll make the assumption there's only one of each).  The easiest way to store this information is to have each member reference the person table.  Now, if you want to expand this so a person has more than one brother, etc, then you'd introduce a new mapping table. :)  Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you describe what that person table relationship would look like please? Preferably in an answer that I can accept. I think you're getting closer to what I want here... @Gerik

Comment: Sure thing. :)  Person is the table, you have a primary key of id, a name attribute, and you have foreign keys which are self-referencing attributes back to the Person table using the primary key. -- In pseudo-code that would look something like: Person[id-PK, name-attribute, mother_id->FK(Person.id), father_id->FK(Person.id), brother_id->FK(Person.id), sister_id->FK(Person.id)].

Comment: Would it work to assign teachers to courses the same as you are for students and check for the users.role_id

Comment: @user765368 There's nothing wrong with having multiple columns in a table that "point to the same table". Look into the difference between domain and role in relational database theory - FK constraints only enforce domain integrity, you can have multiple roles in a table using the same domain. This is also better understood from the perspective of fact-oriented modeling, but confusing if you conflate rows with entities.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you want to handle students and teachers differently (students enroll in a course taught by a specific teacher) but you modeled them the same (they're just users).

Instead of `roles`, create subtypes of `users`. Create tables for `teachers` and `students` - you can reuse the primary keys from `users`, but you'll be able to handle subtype-specific attributes and relationships.

While it's possible to get away with only those entity sets, I suggest you add the concept of a section as well. It has different names in different systems or parts of the world, but most school systems I've seen have something like it to represent a partition of a course's students with an associated teacher.

```
users
- id PK
- username
- password
- first_name
- last_name
- email
- password
- phone
- created
- modified

students
- user_id PK FK

teachers
- user_id PK FK

courses
- id PK
- name
- created
- modified

sections
- section_id PK
- teacher_id FK
- course_id FK
- created
- modified

students_sections
- student_id PK FK
- section_id PK FK
- created
- modified
```

In a real world system, you'll also need to take time into account - students and teachers normally attend different courses in different years or semesters.

Comment: I like your design, but why would you store only user_id in students and teachers table? @reaanb

Comment: I reorganized the original design and didn't want to add my own attributes. Those tables are just starting points, they'll gather student-specific and teacher-specific attributes when this design gets fleshed out.

Comment: And we do agree that between users and students/teachers table, that should be a one-to-one relationship, right?

Comment: ER relationships are represented in tables, not between tables, but if you mean there will be at most only record per user_id in each of those tables, and that the user_id column in students and teachers are subsets of the one in users, then yes.

Comment: *at most only **one**

Comment: yeah that's what I meant

Comment: Why have `created` and `modified`?  "Just in case"?  I'll bet you will never use them.

Comment: @RickJames I'm neither recommending nor opposing the inclusion of those fields - I followed the conventions of the original example so that the two approaches could be easily compared.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply add the “tutor” to the courses table since it’s essential element for a course to know whose is teaching it/tutor.

Then use either the users table or user_courses to join/match and pull the info you want.

```
   **Courses**
- id
- name
-tutorID
- created
- modified
```